# Customizing the flow-layout view by conform Layout protocol didn't work because of the incorrect totalWidth

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, layout

I want to implement a custom flow-layout view via the Layout protocol. Here's my idea for the implementation, I created a Row struct to represent each row of the flow-layout view, and the Row has an array of CGRect's representing the subview content for that row.

In the getRows(subviews:totalWidth:) method, it loops through each subviews, comparing the currently occupied width to the totalWidth to determine whether or not to change lines.

But the final preview result is that all views are displayed in one column, with only one view per row! I printed out some logs, and I found that the value of totalWidth is actually equal to the width of the first child view, that of course will always be a line break. That's the problem, but I don't know what's wrong with it.

Here is my code:

```
struct FlowLayoutView: View {    

    let tags = ["WWDC22", "WWDC23", "SwiftUI", "Swift", "Apple", "iPhone", "iOS", "iPad", "macOS", "M2", "tech", "MacBook", "developer", "news", "coding", "Xcode", "UIKit", "AppKit", "Love", "Hello world!"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            FlowLayoutDemo {
                ForEach(tags, id: \.self) { tag in
                    Button(tag) {}.buttonStyle(.bordered)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .background(.yellow)
        }
    }
}

struct FlowLayoutDemo: Layout {

    var hSpacing: CGFloat = 10
    var vSpacing: CGFloat = 10
    
    struct Row {
        var viewRects: [CGRect] = []

        // The width of each row is the maxX of the last Rect.
        var width: CGFloat { viewRects.last?.maxX ?? 0 }
        // The height of each row is the largest height in the Rect
        var height: CGFloat { viewRects.map(\.height).max() ?? 0 }
    }
    
    private func getRows(subviews: Subviews, totalWidth: CGFloat?) -> [Row] {
        guard let totalWidth, !subviews.isEmpty else { return [] }

        var rows: [Row] = []
        let proposal = ProposedViewSize(width: totalWidth, height: nil)  

        subviews.forEach { view in
            let size = view.sizeThatFits(proposal)
            if rows.isEmpty {
                // The first Rect
                let rect = CGRect(origin: .init(x: 0, y: 0), size: size)
                rows.append(Row(viewRects: [rect]))
            } else {
                var curRow = rows[rows.count - 1]
                let preRect = curRow.viewRects.last!

                if preRect.maxX + hSpacing + size.width > totalWidth {
                    // New line
                    print("rows.count:\(rows.count) - preRect.maxX:\(preRect.maxX) - hSpacing:\(hSpacing) - size.width:\(size.width) - totalWidth:\(totalWidth)")

                    let rect = CGRect(origin: .init(x: 0, y: preRect.minY + curRow.height + vSpacing), size: size)
                    rows.append(Row(viewRects: [rect]))
                } else {
                    // Continue back in the same row
                    let rect = CGRect(origin: .init(x: preRect.maxX + hSpacing, y: preRect.minY), size: size)
                    curRow.viewRects.append(rect)
                }
            }
        }

        return rows;
    }
    
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        let rows = getRows(subviews: subviews, totalWidth: proposal.width)
        
        return .init(width: rows.map(\.width).max() ?? 0, height: rows.last?.viewRects.map(\.maxY).max() ?? 0)
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        let rows = getRows(subviews: subviews, totalWidth: bounds.width)
        var index = 0
        rows.forEach { row in
            row.viewRects.forEach { rect in
                let view = subviews[index]
                defer { index += 1}

                view.place(at: .init(x: rect.minX + bounds.minX,
                                     y: rect.minY + bounds.minY),
                           proposal: .init(rect.size))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The logs:

```
rows.count:1 - preRect.maxX:99.66666666666666 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:89.66666666666666 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:2 - preRect.maxX:89.66666666666666 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:78.66666666666666 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:3 - preRect.maxX:78.66666666666666 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:62.666666666666664 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:4 - preRect.maxX:62.666666666666664 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:68.33333333333333 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:5 - preRect.maxX:68.33333333333333 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:76.33333333333333 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:6 - preRect.maxX:76.33333333333333 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:51.0 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:7 - preRect.maxX:51.0 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:57.0 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:8 - preRect.maxX:57.0 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:79.66666666666666 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:9 - preRect.maxX:79.66666666666666 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:48.33333333333333 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:10 - preRect.maxX:48.33333333333333 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:57.666666666666664 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:11 - preRect.maxX:57.666666666666664 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:95.33333333333333 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:12 - preRect.maxX:95.33333333333333 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:99.66666666666666 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:13 - preRect.maxX:99.66666666666666 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:64.0 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:14 - preRect.maxX:64.0 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:76.0 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:15 - preRect.maxX:76.0 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:72.66666666666666 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:16 - preRect.maxX:72.66666666666666 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:60.666666666666664 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:17 - preRect.maxX:60.666666666666664 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:75.33333333333333 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:18 - preRect.maxX:75.33333333333333 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:60.0 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:19 - preRect.maxX:60.0 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:71.33333333333333 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:1 - preRect.maxX:99.66666666666666 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:89.66666666666666 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:2 - preRect.maxX:89.66666666666666 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:78.66666666666666 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:3 - preRect.maxX:78.66666666666666 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:62.666666666666664 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:4 - preRect.maxX:62.666666666666664 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:68.33333333333333 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:5 - preRect.maxX:68.33333333333333 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:76.33333333333333 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:6 - preRect.maxX:76.33333333333333 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:51.0 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:7 - preRect.maxX:51.0 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:57.0 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:8 - preRect.maxX:57.0 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:79.66666666666666 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:9 - preRect.maxX:79.66666666666666 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:48.33333333333333 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:10 - preRect.maxX:48.33333333333333 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:57.666666666666664 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:11 - preRect.maxX:57.666666666666664 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:95.33333333333333 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:12 - preRect.maxX:95.33333333333333 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:99.66666666666666 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:13 - preRect.maxX:99.66666666666666 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:64.0 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:14 - preRect.maxX:64.0 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:76.0 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:15 - preRect.maxX:76.0 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:72.66666666666666 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:16 - preRect.maxX:72.66666666666666 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:60.666666666666664 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:17 - preRect.maxX:60.666666666666664 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:75.33333333333333 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:18 - preRect.maxX:75.33333333333333 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:60.0 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
rows.count:19 - preRect.maxX:60.0 - hSpacing:10.0 - size.width:71.33333333333333 - totalWidth:99.66666666666666
```

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [how other people did it](https://github.com/tevelee/SwiftUI-Flow)? Or just use that directly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Row` is a `struct`. So in `getRows`, when you think you are updating an existing row, you are only updating a copy of the existing row and the existing row remains unchanged. The first time the function is called, it delivers an array of rows containing only 1 row and that single row contains only a single rectangle.

Here are two ways to fix it:

**1. Update the rows directly**

In the function `getRows`, change the loop to refer to the rows using an index into the `rows` array, instead of copying from the array:

```swift
for view in subviews {
    let size = view.sizeThatFits(proposal)
    if let lastRow = rows.last {
        let preRect = lastRow.viewRects.last!
        if preRect.maxX + hSpacing + size.width > totalWidth {

            // New line
//            print("rows.count:\(rows.count) - preRect.maxX:\(preRect.maxX) - hSpacing:\(hSpacing) - size.width:\(size.width) - totalWidth:\(totalWidth)")

            let rect = CGRect(origin: .init(x: 0, y: preRect.minY + lastRow.height + vSpacing), size: size)
            rows.append(Row(viewRects: [rect]))
        } else {

            // Append to the same row
            let rect = CGRect(origin: .init(x: preRect.maxX + hSpacing, y: preRect.minY), size: size)
            let curIndex = rows.count - 1
            rows[curIndex].viewRects.append(rect)
        }
    } else {

        // No rows yet, so this is the first Rect
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .init(x: 0, y: 0), size: size)
        rows.append(Row(viewRects: [rect]))
    }
}
```

**2. Change `Row` to be a `class`**

If a `Row` is a `class` then it does not get copied when it is extracted from the array.

```swift
class Row {
    var viewRects: [CGRect]
    init(viewRects: [CGRect]) {
        self.viewRects = viewRects
    }

    // Rest of implementation unchanged
}
```

Comment: But I still don't know why this affects the value of totalWidth. totalWidth shouldn't change the first time it is passed in. Could  you please explain that in detail?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, the first time the getRows function was being called it was returning an array containing only one row and this single row contained only one rectangle, this being the first rectangle. So after that, layout was being based on this very narrow width.

Comment: But in your 1st answer,  the first time the getRows function was returning an array containing only one row and one rect too.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to. This was why the size of the container was being computed incorrectly which in turn impacted the end layout. With the code corrected, the size of the container is now being computed correctly and layout works as intended.